# Optaplanner : View intermediate score

Tags: optaplanner

Is there a way keep track of the score from time to time while the solver is running?

I currently instantiate my solver as follow

```
SolverFactory solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource("solver/SolverConfig.xml");
Solver solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
solver.addEventListener(new SolverEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void bestSolutionChanged(BestSolutionChangedEvent event) {
        logger.info("New best score : " + event.getNewBestScore().toShortString());
    }
});
solver.solve(planningSolution);
```

This way I am able to see the logs every time the best score changes.

However, I would like to view the score after every 100 steps or after every 10 seconds. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn on DEBUG (or TRACE) logging, you'll see it.
If you want to listen to it in java, that's not supported in the public API, but there's `PhaseLifecycleListener` in the internal implementation that has no backward compatibility guarantees...